# Windows WIFI Icon showing as not Not Connect but has WIFI

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

[image]

For some reason the WIFI icon on my taskbar is showing not connected when I am obviously connected since about a week back. I ran the wireless adapter and internet connections (in settings) troubleshooter and nothing came up. The only way to fix it currently is to disconnect and reconnect the wifi. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the below fix your problem? If not i may have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have your Wireless driver locally on hand.

Now in Device Manager, remove the wireless driver.

Restart, and install the wireless driver from the first step.

Verify you have Internet.

Now run DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete
```

Finally, restart and by reinstalling the wireless driver and running DISM, the icon should now be there.

Comment: Have you disabled the Network Connectivity Status indicator, e.g., with ShutUp10?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by having it "locally on hand"? Does this entail having in a USB or like on my disk? If so, how do I get it? (I probably sound dumb)

Comment: I meant that you should download the driver. When you uninstall the wireless driver, you will need the driver to install and then connect.